# Linq XML descendants being lost on enumeration

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have an XML document like this

```
<root>
  <item id="1" creator="me">
    <childA>1</childA>
    <childB>2</childB>
  </item>
  <item id="2" creator="me">
    <childA>1</childA>
    <childB>3</childB>
    <childB>4</childB>
  </item>
</root>
```

I'm trying to find duplicate items, then again duplicate child items for the duplicate items with logic like this

```
XDocument XmlRoot //whatever...you get the point

// Get item nodes
var items = XmlRoot.Descendants("item");

// Find duplicate items keys using creator attribute
var duplicateItemKeys = items.GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("creator").Value)
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.Select(g => g.Key);

foreach(var duplicateItemKey in duplicateItemKeys)
{
  // Get the duplicate item XML elements using the duplicate keys
  var duplicateItems = items.Where(x => x.Attribute("creator").Value == duplicateToucheKey)
      .OrderBy(xelement => xelement.Attribute("CreatedOn").Value);
}
```

This works, however there is a problem later when I try to use duplicateItems. Any time it enumerates (like in a foreach duplicateItems) the first item looses the context of it's children. The second one is just fine.

So for example, later in code I say

```
var allItemB = new List<XElement>();
foreach (duplicateItem in duplicateItems) 
{
  allItemB.AddRange(duplicateItem.Descendants("childB"));
}
```

I expect "allItemB" to contain 2 on the first pass, then 234 on the second. What ends up happening is that it only contains 34 because once the duplicateItems array is enumerated the first XElement looses it's children.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is the desired result of the first part?  Does it have to stay as an XElement or can it be a dictionary of 'child', 'values concatenated'?

Comment: Ideally, I'm trying to parse the XML for duplicates, then reassemble it and send it back to the database.

Comment: What is considered a duplicate?  Duplicate tag name, values, attribute names, attribute values?

Comment: Two duplicates, get by duplicate tag name with duplicate creator. Trying to untangle duplicate objects for a merge scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want allItemB to have 3 elements - allItemB[0] is the XElement childB with value 2, [1] to be 3 and [2] to be 4?

If so, the problem is where you are declaring duplicateItems.  Your code same doesn't even compile, as the variable's scope is limited to the first foreach loop, and thus not available at the second.

My code to get the above result:

```
XDocument XmlRoot = XDocument.Load( "C:\\somefile.xml" );

// Get item nodes
var items = XmlRoot.Descendants("item");

// Find duplicate items keys using creator attribute
var duplicateItemKeys = items.GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("creator").Value)
     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
     .Select(g => g.Key);

IEnumerable<XElement> duplicateItems = new List<XElement>();
foreach(var duplicateItemKey in duplicateItemKeys)
{
     // Get the duplicate item XML elements using the duplicate keys
     duplicateItems = items.Where(x => x.Attribute("creator").Value == duplicateItemKey)
          .OrderBy(xelement => xelement.Attribute("id").Value);
 }

 var allItemB = new List<XElement>();
 foreach (var duplicateItem in duplicateItems) 
 {
      allItemB.AddRange(duplicateItem.Descendants("childB"));
 }
```

Edit: forgot to mention that I changed the OrderBy in the first foreach loop because the sample xml file didn't have the CreatedOn attribute.

And if you want, you can use a little more Linq and drop the foreach loops entirely, like so:

```
XDocument XmlRoot = XDocument.Load( "C:\\somefile.xml" );

// Get item nodes
var items = XmlRoot.Descendants("item");

// Find duplicate items keys using creator attribute
var duplicateItemKeys = items.GroupBy(x => x.Attribute("creator").Value)
     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
     .Select(g => g.Key);

// Get the duplicate item XML elements using the duplicate keys
var duplicateItems = items.Where(i => duplicateItemKeys.Contains(i.Attribute("creator").Value))
     .OrderBy( xelement => xelement.Attribute("id").Value );

// Get the child nodes named childB
var allItemB = new List<XElement>();
allItemB.AddRange( duplicateItems.Descendants("childB") );
```

Comment: Yes, my code didn't compile because I mistakenly copied and pasted from some other code. Sorry about that. I can't believe that I didn't notice the scope of my duplicateItems var was incorrect! I feel like such a fool. Thanks for the help!