# How to find equal elements with common parent in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I need to find places in XML, where elements are duplicated. For example, in XML like the following:

```
<menu>
  <juice sugar="yes" fresh="no">
    <apple/>
    <carrot/>
  </juice>
  <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
    <apple/>
    <carrot/>
  </juice>
  <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
    <carrot/>
    <apple/>
  </juice>
  <juice>
    <carrot kind="village" />
    <orange/>
  <juice/>
  <juice>
    <carrot kind="village" />
    <orange/>
    <carrot kind="village" />
  </juice>
</menu>
```

I need is to throw an exception, if my XML contains equal elements with common parent. However attributes also are important and should be equal.

The order of the descendants should not be important. That means, in my example exception should be thrown for

```
  <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
    <apple/>
    <carrot/>
  </juice>
  <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
    <carrot/>
    <apple/>
  </juice>
```

since "juices" have all attributes equal and children of the second "juice" are permuted children of the first one.

Another place, where an exception should occur is:

```
  <juice>
    <carrot kind="village" />
    <orange/>
    <carrot kind="village" />
  </juice>
```

since "juice" contains the same "carrot" twice.`

I will be grateful for any hint for this problem. Should I use XSLT? Or may be it is better to deserialize my XML in C#?

Comment: take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371200/linq-xml-descendants-being-lost-on-enumeration) they are doing the something similar to what you are trying to do ... but I would rather go with [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) and deserialize the xml into objects.

Comment: This can be achieved by using XSLT also.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your responses. I solved my problem with C# and XmlDocument class. Fortunately I discovered, that it is enough to check only nodes with certain attributes and there was no need in deserializing. I just recursively checked descendants of each node.

Answer (score 2):

I would first turn each element into canonical form by sorting the children into order; this is easily done with XSLT. The result should be such that two elements are equal according to your rules if and only if their canonical forms are deep-equal() according to XPath 2.0.

I would then write a function that computes some kind of hashcode for each element (so that "equal" elements have equal hashcodes) and perform grouping on this hashcode. Again this is easily done with XSLT 2.0: the only difficult bit is designing the hash function. I suspect your example doesn't show the real data, and I would want to see the real data before suggesting a hash function.

Then within each hashcode group you can use XSLT 2.0's deep-equal() function to compare every member of the group against every other, to eliminate cases where the hashcode match is spurious.

Comment: Hi Michael! Thanks for your response. Do you mean, that in XSL it is possible to perform sorting with deep comparing easily? Or may be you mean turning on within each node a recurrent sorting with trivial comparing. In the last case it does not work, since if we have:
    <menu>
      <juice>  <orange />  </juice>
      <juice>  <apple />  </juice>
    </menu>
XML is sorted everywhere with response to trivial comparing, however XML is not sorted deeply.

Comment: In particular, it is not in canonical form (I mean it is not uniquely presented, since we can change an order of the "juices" and our "sort" will not notify this. Moreover the new menu will be another menu in the eyes of deep sorting.
Is it possible to easily sort with deep comparing?

Comment: Sorry you haven't understood the algorithm I was describing but I don't have time just now to explain it in simpler language. It's not that dissimilar from Ken's solution, but his has quadratic performance, while I was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT 2.0 solution below happens to work with your data set.  If you have more data to run through it, that would help test how robust it is.

```
t:\ftemp>type viktoria.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu>
  <juice sugar="yes" fresh="no">
    <apple/>
    <carrot/>
  </juice>
  <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
    <apple/>
    <carrot/>
  </juice>
  <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
    <carrot/>
    <apple/>
  </juice>
  <juice>
    <carrot kind="village" />
    <orange/>
  </juice>
  <juice>
    <carrot kind="village" />
    <orange/>
    <carrot kind="village" />
  </juice>
</menu>

t:\ftemp>call xslt2 viktoria.xml viktoria.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exceptions>
   <duplicates>
      <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
         <apple/>
         <carrot/>
      </juice>
      <juice sugar="no" fresh="no">
         <carrot/>
         <apple/>
      </juice>
   </duplicates>
   <children>
      <juice>
         <carrot kind="village"/>
         <orange/>
         <carrot kind="village"/>
      </juice>
   </children>
</exceptions>

t:\ftemp>type viktoria.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:v="urn:X-Viktoria" exclude-result-prefixes="v xsd"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<!--return true if the two elements and their attributes are the same while
    ignoring children-->
<xsl:function name="v:shallow-equal" as="xsd:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="elem1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="elem2" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="node-name($elem1)=node-name($elem2) and
    ( every $a1 in $elem1/@* satisfies ( some $a2 in $elem2/@* satisfies 
        ( node-name($a1)=node-name($a2)  and $a1 = $a2 ) ) ) and
    ( every $a2 in $elem2/@* satisfies ( some $a1 in $elem1/@* satisfies 
        ( node-name($a1)=node-name($a2)  and $a1 = $a2 ) ) )"/>
</xsl:function>

<!--return true if two elements have the same children with the same attributes
    while ignoring the children's children-->
<xsl:function name="v:element-and-children-equal" as="xsd:boolean">
  <xsl:param name="elem1" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:param name="elem2" as="element()"/>
  <xsl:sequence
    select="v:shallow-equal($elem1,$elem2) and
            ( every $child1 in $elem1/* satisfies 
                count( $elem2/*[deep-equal(.,$child1)] )=1 ) and
            ( every $child2 in $elem2/* satisfies 
                count( $elem1/*[deep-equal(.,$child2)] )=1 )"/>
</xsl:function>

<!--produce result-->
<xsl:template match="menu">
  <exceptions>
    <duplicates>
      <!--find each element that has a sibling with same children, that is,
          there is more than one such element amongst all siblings-->
      <xsl:for-each 
        select="*[ for $this in . return
              count ( ../*[v:element-and-children-equal(.,$this)] ) > 1 ]">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </duplicates>
    <children>
      <!--find each element that has duplicate children, that is,
          there is more than one of each child amongst all children-->
      <xsl:for-each
        select="*[ some $child in * satisfies
                   count ( *[deep-equal(.,$child)] ) >1 ]">
       <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </children>
  </exceptions>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```